# CSS text-align property is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a problem with this script.

The output is not aligned to the center; only the red color works fine.

```
<script>      
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#register_form input").focus(function () {
            $("#status").fadeOut(800);
        });

        $("#pass1").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length < 6) {
                $("#output_pass1").css("color", "red").css('text-align', 'center').html("<br/><br/>very short ");

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the HTML code:

```
<label for="pass1">Password :</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="Password" id="pass1" placeholder="Enter your password " required>
</div>

<small id="output_pass1" ></small>
```

Comment: please show more html code.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to work?

Comment: Do you have any other CSS applied to your tag? (Not via JS)

Answer (score 1):

Please give the element `display: block;`, too:

```
small { display: block; }
```

or

```
$("#output_pass1")
.css({"color":"red", "text-align":"center", "display": "block" })
.html("<br/><br/>very short ");
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/NDNYF/5/

Comment: you're welcome John Low, 
Thank you Toothbrush for correcting grammatic mistake.